# how to handle java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CallableStatement.closeOnCompletion()

Tags: java

I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar with jdk7 and tomcat7 but my code is giving abstractMethodError while executing callableStatement.closeOnCompletion().Code is given below :

try {

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    CallableStatement st = session.connection().prepareCall(
    "{call getOfflineNodes('" + strDevice + "',"
    + System.currentTimeMillis() + "," + polltime + ","+ status + ")}");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    st.closeOnCompletion();
    tx.commit();
    HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    return rs;
}
```

and complete exception is :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CallableStatement.closeOnCompletion()V
at com.clearcube.util.DMLLayer.getOfflineNodes(DMLLayer.java:90)
at com.clearcube.logging.ShutBladeAlertService.<init>(ShutBladeAlertService.java:80)
at com.clearcube.common.CMSServiceLoaderServlet.init(CMSServiceLoaderServlet.java:95)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

can anybody tell me why this exception is coming and how to handle this.

code where i am using this returned resultSet is :

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
          public void run()
          {
            String bladeMacs = "";
            String vmMacs = "";
            try
            {
              int poll = Integer.parseInt(
                ServerConfigurationService.getProperty("blade.refresh.time"));

              Calendar callendar = Calendar.getInstance();

              String strblade = "";
              String strvm = "";
              String Ip = "";
              ResultSet BladeRs = (ResultSet)DMLLayer.getOfflineNodes(
                "Blade", poll, 1);
              if (BladeRs != null) {
                boolean isBladeAlive = false;
                int x = 0;
                try {
                  while (BladeRs.next()) {

                    String mac = BladeRs.getString("macAddress");
                    String ip = BladeRs.getString("Ip");
                    isBladeAlive = 
                      EchoUDPClientDiscoveryObjectResponse.echo(InetAddress.getByName(BladeRs
                      .getString("Ip")), 6502, "any", 
                      3, 500);

                    if (!isBladeAlive) {

                      if (x > 0)
                      {
                        strblade = strblade + "\n";
                        bladeMacs = bladeMacs + "\n";
                      }

                      strblade = strblade + ip;
                      x = 2;
                      bladeMacs = bladeMacs + mac;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String query = "update DiscoveredNode set DateModified=:DateModified where MacAddress=:MacAddress";

                      ShutBladeAlertService.objTypeVector.removeAllElements();
                      ShutBladeAlertService.objFieldVector.removeAllElements();
                      ShutBladeAlertService.objValueVector.removeAllElements();

                      ShutBladeAlertService.objTypeVector.add("Long");
                      ShutBladeAlertService.objFieldVector.add("DateModified");
                      ShutBladeAlertService.objValueVector.add(
                        Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                      ShutBladeAlertService.objTypeVector.add("String");
                      ShutBladeAlertService.objFieldVector.add("MacAddress");
                      ShutBladeAlertService.objValueVector.add(mac);

                      DMLLayer.runUpdateQuery(query, 
                        ShutBladeAlertService.objFieldVector, ShutBladeAlertService.objValueVector, 
                        ShutBladeAlertService.objTypeVector);
                    }
                  }

                  BladeRs.close();

                }
                catch (Exception ex1) {
                  ex1.printStackTrace();
                }

              }
          }
      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`closeOnCompletion()` exists since Java 7. And the driver has been implemented with a previous version of the interface. So this method is not implemented by the MySQL driver.

Find if a more recent version exists with support for this method (but it doesn't seem to exist), or avoid calling this method.

Comment: 5.1.20 is latest driver that I am using. I need to call this method as I am using resultSet returned from this function in other code processing.Is there any other way to close the callableStatement after checking number of resultSets open.

Comment: Everyone was able to use JDBC before this method existed, so you should be able to do it. Call all your other processings, and when they're finished, close the statement.

Comment: I am not closing statement after getting resultSet . Statement is closed automatically while I am processing resultSet and showing following exception ;

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
16:48:15,184 ERROR  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
16:48:15,184 ERROR  at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkClosed(ResultSet.java:641)
16:48:15,184 ERROR  at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:6437)

Comment: I have edit my question and add code where I am using returned resultSet. Please see that too and give me any solution please...

Comment: Don't return result sets. Call the methods using the result sets from the method opening them, and when the method using the result set returns, then call the statement: `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
someObject.doSomethingWithResultSet(rs);st.close();`